# How to use csquotes foreignquotes with RTL languages?

Tags: csquotes, bidi

I'm having trouble getting `csquotes` foreign quotes to work neatly with RTL languages (in my case Hebrew). Am I doing something wrong or is there a bug somewhere?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\subsection*{foreigntextquote}
\subsubsection*{What I get:}
Genesis begins \foreigntextquote{hebrew}[Gen 1:1][.]{בְּרֵאשִׁית בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם
וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ}.
\subsubsection*{What I want:}
Genesis begins \textquote[Gen 1:1][.]{\texthebrew{בְּרֵאשִׁית בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם
וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ}}.
\subsection*{foreigndisplayquote}
\subsubsection*{What I get:}
\begin{foreigndisplayquote}{hebrew}[Gen 1:1]
בְּרֵאשִׁית בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ.
\end{foreigndisplayquote}
\subsubsection*{What I want:}
\begin{quote}
  \begin{hebrew}
    בְּרֵאשִׁית בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ. \textenglish{(Gen 1:1)}
  \end{hebrew}
\end{quote}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As the output is wrong,  it is a bug. On the other side: bidi-typesetting is challenging. And the csquotes code contains grouping and look-aheads and finding out, why it fails is not easy. (One part of the problem is probably that csquotes uses `otherlanguage*`, which doesn't change directions, but changing this alone doesn't correct the direction inside the \foreignquote and similar.)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, yes, so I am seeing as I poke through the `csquotes.sty` file. It needs a `\RLforeignquote` and variants. If I'm feeling keen, I'll see how hard it is to implement something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess `csquote` got updated in the meantime (using csquotes.sty    2021-02-22 v5.2l). I used the font `Linux Libertine O`.

**"UPDATE" (with the quotes)**

(1) I corrected a misplaced dot and an extra space in "What I want" (marked in the code) to show the results looks the same.

(2) Hebrew is not currently supported by `csquotes` so I added  `\DeclareQuoteStyle{hebrew}` using the definition from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_punctuation.

(3) The spaces can be controlled using the second optional argument of `foreigndisplayquote`. `\begin{foreigndisplayquote}{⟨ lang⟩ }[⟨ cite⟩ ][⟨ punct⟩ ]`

Now the output looks fine.

[image: zz]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}

\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Ligatures=NoCommon]{Linux Libertine O}   

\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}   

\DeclareQuoteStyle{hebrew}% from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_punctuation
{\textquotedblright}
{\textquotedblright}
[0.05em]
{\textquoteright}
{\textquoteright}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}    

\subsection*{foreigntextquote}
\subsubsection*{What I get:}
Genesis begins \foreigntextquote{hebrew}[Gen 1:1][.]{בְּרֵאשִׁית בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם
    וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ}.
\subsubsection*{What I want:} %corrected [] instead of [.] <<<<<
Genesis begins \textquote[Gen 1:1][]{\texthebrew{בְּרֵאשִׁית בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם
        וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ.}}. 
\subsection*{foreigndisplayquote}
\subsubsection*{What I get:}
\begin{foreigndisplayquote}{hebrew}[Gen 1:1][\,] %using the optional argument to insert a space
    בְּרֵאשִׁית בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ.  
\end{foreigndisplayquote}
\subsubsection*{What I want:}% corrected extra space removed before the dot <<<<<
\begin{quote}
    \begin{hebrew}
        בְּרֵאשִׁית בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ.\textenglish{(Gen 1:1)\,}
    \end{hebrew}
\end{quote}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Necromancer :)

Comment: Indeed, it's better, but still a few differences in both kinds of quotes.

Comment: @David Purton Are you referring to the differences between "What I want" and "What I get" or the position of `(Gen 1: 1)` ?

Comment: @SimonDispa between what I want and what I get. Your screen shot shows no space between (Gen 1:1) and the quote in the foreigndisplayquote. And the quote marks are the wrong way around in the foreigntextquote.

Comment: @David Purton I updated the answer. Since Hebrew is not currently supported by `csquotes`  I added a  `\DeclareQuoteStyle{hebrew}` using the definition from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_punctuation.
The spaces can be controlled using the second optional argument of `foreigndisplayquote`.

Comment: @DavidPurton I still have the same issue as op. Your code gives me the Hebrew words in the wrong direction. To check whether this is the result of later updates to `csquotes`: does this still work for you? (I use the most recent version, csquotes.sty 5.2n 2022-09-14.)