# Biblatex Localized Items

Tags: biblatex, arabic

I am preparing a document where I am using Biblatex + Polyglyossia + XELATEX. I have citations in both languages English and Arabic. The localized items appear in English in Arabic citations, also upon using the cs quotes package which is a must in biblatex package, CS QUOTES have no quotation for Arabic language. I have 3 issues:

- How to make footnote citations and bibliography change from right to left or left to right according to language
- Localized items (the words edition, page,seenote,and), how to remove them or make them appear according to the citation language
- CS quotes have no definition for Arabic language.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,margin=2.5cm,bindingoffset=0.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{polyglossia} 
\setdefaultlanguage[calendar=gregorian,locale=default,numerals=mashriq]{arabic}
\setotherlanguages{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Mapping=arabicdigits]{Simplified Arabic} 
\usepackage[backend=biber,language=autobib,autolang=hyphen,citestyle=verbose-note,bibstyle=authortitle,doi=false,isbn=false,block=none,]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{D:/SC/PROJ/Subfile Package Solution - Biblatex/With_all_set_up.bib} 
\title{}
\author{}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\chapter{}
مع المثلة مثال
\footcite[256]{Sharoni1969}
\newpage
مع المثلة مثال
\footcite{Sharoni1969}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Here is the reference format

```
@book{Sharoni1969,
 author = {ميخائيل، ملاك  and  الشاروني، حبيب},
 year = {1969},
 title = {المرجع فى قواعد اللغة القبطية},
 address = {الاسكندرية},
 publisher = {{جمعية مارمينا العجايبي}}
}

@book{Browning1983,
 author = {Browning, Robert},
 year = {1983},
 title = {Medieval and Modern Greek},
 publisher = {{Cambridge University Press}},
 isbn = {0521299780 9780521299787}
}
```

[image: p.1]
[image: p.2]
[image: Bibliography]

Comment: You might be out of luck with getting `csquotes` to work with Arabic. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375051/how-to-use-csquotes-foreignquotes-with-rtl-languages. I had a go at implementing this at https://github.com/dcpurton/csquotes-bidi, but it's pretty dodgy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I couldn't do this with `polyglossia` and `xelatex`.

But here's a go with `babel` and `lualatex` that might offer a way forward.

You have to create `arabic.lbx` for strings for `biblatex` and define Arabic quotes for `csquotes`. (I'm not sure about either the quotes or the translations…)

## MWE

There's some comments in the code below explaining things a bit.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Sharoni1969,
 author = {ميخائيل، ملاك  and  الشاروني، حبيب},
 year = {1969},
 title = {المرجع فى قواعد اللغة القبطية},
 address = {الاسكندرية},
 publisher = {جمعية مارمينا العجايبي},
 langid = {arabic}
}
@book{Browning1983,
 author = {Browning, Robert},
 year = {1983},
 title = {Medieval and Modern Greek},
 publisher = {Cambridge University Press},
 langid = {english}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{arabic.lbx}
\ProvidesFile{arabic.lbx}
\InheritBibliographyExtras{english}
% Translations thanks to Google Translate.
% I haven't provided abbreviations, because I don't know Arabic.
% You'll need to add more for other strings you use.
% Look in `english.lbx` for the string name.
\DeclareBibliographyStrings{%
  inherit          = {english},
  and              = {{و}{و}},
  page             = {{صفحة}{صفحة}},
  pages            = {{صفحات}{صفحة}},
  references       = {{مراجع}{مراجع}},
  seenote          = {{انظر الملاحظة}{انظر الملاحظة}},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[nil,bidi=basic-r]{babel}
\babelprovide[import=ar,mapdigits,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import=en,language=Default]{english}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Amiri}
\babelfont[english]{rm}{Latin Modern Roman}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\DeclareQuoteStyle{arabic}
  {\guillemotleft}
  {\guillemotright}
  {\textquotedblright}
  {\textquotedblleft}

\usepackage[language=auto,autolang=other,citestyle=verbose-note,bibstyle=authortitle,doi=false,isbn=false]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
  {\list
     {}
     {\setlength{\leftmargin}{\bibhang}%
      \setlength{\itemindent}{-\leftmargin}%
      \setlength{\itemsep}{\bibitemsep}%
      \setlength{\parsep}{\bibparsep}}}
  {\endlist}
  {\item\leavevmode}% add \leavevmode to align English bibliography items RTL

% Always use Arabic digits for see note.
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{footcite:note}
  {\ref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}}
  {\foreignlanguage{arabic}{\ref{cbx@\csuse{cbx@f@\thefield{entrykey}}}}}
  {}
  {}

% Just to test if quotes work
\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\mkbibquote{\mkbibemph{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill
مع المثلة مثال \autocite[256]{Sharoni1969}.
مع المثلة مثال \autocite{Sharoni1969}.

مع المثلة مثال \autocite[256]{Browning1983}.
مع المثلة مثال \autocite{Browning1983}.

% With the above, the language changes back to Arabic before the final period
% is inserted, so it ends up being to the left of the note. This looks a bit
% odd to me, but the only way I could get the period at the right hand side of
% the note was to put it inside a footnote like this:
مع المثلة مثال\footnote{\cite{Browning1983}.}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: @ David: I have only one issue with this solution, I am using other languages including "Coptic, Greek, Cyriac, Hebrew, Hungarian" and I need to use the system fonts "OTF" fonts used by windows. Is this allowable with babel and lualatex??

Comment: your solution is flawless, I used you exact solution with a little modification, I replaced the babel package with polyglyossia, and everything worked except the part where you want the english text to be aligned from left to right, can you help me out?? Also the word bibliography is in English not arabic

Comment: @Silva, I was unable to get things working satisfactorily with `polyglossia` and `xelatex`. I think that `biblatex` does not work well with RTL languages with the `bidi` package. Hence my answer with `lualatex` and `babel`. There is no problem using system OTF fonts with `lualatex` and `babel`. You have complete control over what font you want to use for what language.

Comment: @Silva, I will see if I can provide and answer to your question at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/504609/biblatex-usage-for-multiple-languages-in-same-citation to show usage for the different fonts.

Comment: @ if that is the case, the I would be grateful if you can help me out regarding defining the following languages along with their otf fonts since I am currently using all of them:

Comment: Regarding the coptic language, it has been mentioned that "There is no babel Coptic language definition file, at least for now. When
the Coptic language is invoked only its alphabet and its hyphenation rules are
used, but it is not the same as specifying a coptic option to the babel
package; this means that commands such as \selectlanguage{coptic} DO NOT WORK." (https://ctan.org/pkg/cbcoptic), Will this be an issue? Also Hieroglyph and Cyriac  can't find them

Comment: I just asked a relevant question to this at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/505615/how-to-set-up-a-new-rtl-language-for-babel-using-ini-files. I think it will be quite easy to set up new languages for `babel`.

Comment: @Silva, Though I don't know about hyphenation. I do think that increasingly `babel` will be the best option though. `polyglossia` is not really actively maintained. But `babel` and `lualatex` are getting many improvements.

Comment: I am sorry, but how do I add the page number for repeated citations. As you can see, when you repeat a citation it says (See note 2 ...) how can I add page number, for example: "See note 2, p.10" such that this page number always refers to the original page of the first time this citation was references. Also, In case I include page nunmbers to the citations in the full cite command, how can the command be set to refer to the first incident of this citation with the same page number, else it puts the citation as if it is a new one?

Comment: @Silva, please ask a new question and reference this question for context. That way more people will see it.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/531567/biblatex-and-footcite-configurations

Comment: @ David Purton, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/574854/biblatex-numeric-citation-style-not-working-in-arabic-document-with-multilingu