# How can I get csquotes and babel to set a display environment RTL (for Hebrew or Syriac)?

Tags: babel, csquotes, bidi

I'm using `csquotes` and `babel` (compiled with LuaLaTeX in case that's significant) with text primarily in English but quoting Hebrew and Syriac which needs to be set RTL. Everything works, with the exception of the `csquotes` environments for foreign languages, which do not correctly switch to RTL for display environments. MWE shows the problem - the Hebrew paragraph is set LTR.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes} % language-aware quoting and display environments
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[bidi=basic, english]{babel}

%
% Languages
%
\babelprovide[import=en-GB,main]{british}
\babelprovide[onchar=ids,fonts,import=he,mapfont=direction]{hebrew}

\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}[
  Ligatures = TeX,
  Contextuals=Alternate,
  ItalicFont = TaameyDavidCLM-MediumOblique,
  BoldFont = TaameyDavidCLM-Bold,
  BoldItalicFont = TaameyDavidCLM-BoldOblique]%
  {TaameyDavidCLM-Medium}

\begin{document}

\begin{foreigndisplayquote}{hebrew}[Jer 32.1–5]
    ‏ הַדָּבָר אֲשֶׁר־הָיָה אֶל־יִרְמְיָהוּ מֵאֵת יְהוָה בִּשְׁנַת [בַּ][שָּׁנָה] הָעֲשִׂרִית לְצִדְקִיָּהוּ מֶלֶךְ יְהוּדָה הִיא הַשָּׁנָה שְׁמֹנֶה־עֶשְׂרֵה שָׁנָה לִנְבוּכַדְרֶאצַּר׃ ‎2‏ וְאָז חֵיל מֶלֶךְ בָּבֶל צָרִים עַל־יְרוּשָׁלִָם וְיִרְמְיָהוּ הַנָּבִיא הָיָה כָלוּא בַּחֲצַר הַמַּטָּרָה אֲשֶׁר בֵּית־מֶלֶךְ יְהוּדָה׃ ‎3‏ אֲשֶׁר כְּלָאוֹ צִדְקִיָּהוּ מֶלֶךְ־יְהוּדָה לֵאמֹר מַדּוּעַ אַתָּה נִבָּא לֵאמֹר כֹּה אָמַר יְהוָה הִנְנִי נֹתֵן אֶת־הָעִיר הַזֹּאת בְּיַד מֶלֶךְ־בָּבֶל וּלְכָדָהּ׃ ‎4‏ וְצִדְקִיָּהוּ מֶלֶךְ יְהוּדָה לֹא יִמָּלֵט מִיַּד הַכַּשְׂדִּים כִּי הִנָּתֹן יִנָּתֵן בְּיַד מֶלֶךְ־בָּבֶל וְדִבֶּר־פִּיו עִם־פִּיו וְעֵינָיו אֶת־עֵינָו [עֵינָיו] תִּרְאֶינָה׃ ‎5‏ וּבָבֶל יוֹלִךְ אֶת־צִדְקִיָּהוּ וְשָׁם יִהְיֶה עַד־פָּקְדִי אֹתוֹ נְאֻם־יְהוָה כִּי תִלָּחֲמוּ אֶת־הַכַּשְׂדִּים לֹא תַצְלִיחוּ׃ פ
\end{foreigndisplayquote}
\begin{displayquote}[Jer 32.1–5]
    The word that came to Jeremiah from the LORD in the tenth year of King Zedekiah of Judah, which was the eighteenth year of Nebuchadrezzar. 2 At that time the army of the king of Babylon was besieging Jerusalem, and the prophet Jeremiah was confined in the court of the guard that was in the palace of the king of Judah, 3 where King Zedekiah of Judah had confined him. Zedekiah had said, “Why do you prophesy and say: Thus says the LORD: I am going to give this city into the hand of the king of Babylon, and he shall take it; 4 King Zedekiah of Judah shall not escape out of the hands of the Chaldeans, but shall surely be given into the hands of the king of Babylon, and shall speak with him face to face and see him eye to eye; 5 and he shall take Zedekiah to Babylon, and there he shall remain until I attend to him, says the LORD; though you fight against the Chaldeans, you shall not succeed?”
\end{displayquote}

\selectlanguage{hebrew}

‏ הַדָּבָר אֲשֶׁר־הָיָה אֶל־יִרְמְיָהוּ מֵאֵת יְהוָה בִּשְׁנַת [בַּ][שָּׁנָה] הָעֲשִׂרִית לְצִדְקִיָּהוּ מֶלֶךְ יְהוּדָה הִיא הַשָּׁנָה שְׁמֹנֶה־עֶשְׂרֵה שָׁנָה לִנְבוּכַדְרֶאצַּר׃ ‎2‏ וְאָז חֵיל מֶלֶךְ בָּבֶל צָרִים עַל־יְרוּשָׁלִָם וְיִרְמְיָהוּ הַנָּבִיא הָיָה כָלוּא בַּחֲצַר הַמַּטָּרָה אֲשֶׁר בֵּית־מֶלֶךְ יְהוּדָה׃ ‎3‏ אֲשֶׁר כְּלָאוֹ צִדְקִיָּהוּ מֶלֶךְ־יְהוּדָה לֵאמֹר מַדּוּעַ אַתָּה נִבָּא לֵאמֹר כֹּה אָמַר יְהוָה הִנְנִי נֹתֵן אֶת־הָעִיר הַזֹּאת בְּיַד מֶלֶךְ־בָּבֶל וּלְכָדָהּ׃ ‎4‏ וְצִדְקִיָּהוּ מֶלֶךְ יְהוּדָה לֹא יִמָּלֵט מִיַּד הַכַּשְׂדִּים כִּי הִנָּתֹן יִנָּתֵן בְּיַד מֶלֶךְ־בָּבֶל וְדִבֶּר־פִּיו עִם־פִּיו וְעֵינָיו אֶת־עֵינָו [עֵינָיו] תִּרְאֶינָה׃ ‎5‏ וּבָבֶל יוֹלִךְ אֶת־צִדְקִיָּהוּ וְשָׁם יִהְיֶה עַד־פָּקְדִי אֹתוֹ נְאֻם־יְהוָה כִּי תִלָּחֲמוּ אֶת־הַכַּשְׂדִּים לֹא תַצְלִיחוּ׃ פ

\selectlanguage{british}

The word that came to Jeremiah from the LORD in the tenth year of King Zedekiah of Judah, which was the eighteenth year of Nebuchadrezzar. 2 At that time the army of the king of Babylon was besieging Jerusalem, and the prophet Jeremiah was confined in the court of the guard that was in the palace of the king of Judah, 3 where King Zedekiah of Judah had confined him. Zedekiah had said, “Why do you prophesy and say: Thus says the LORD: I am going to give this city into the hand of the king of Babylon, and he shall take it; 4 King Zedekiah of Judah shall not escape out of the hands of the Chaldeans, but shall surely be given into the hands of the king of Babylon, and shall speak with him face to face and see him eye to eye; 5 and he shall take Zedekiah to Babylon, and there he shall remain until I attend to him, says the LORD; though you fight against the Chaldeans, you shall not succeed?”

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE screenshot]

I noted this earlier question:

[How to use csquotes foreignquotes with RTL languages?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375051/how-to-use-csquotes-foreignquotes-with-rtl-languages)

which addresses the situation with `polyglossia` and perhaps the situation is the same with my attempt to use `babel`?

Comment: Note the second `\babelprovide` is not quite correct. Use the following instead: `\babelprovide[onchar=ids fonts,import]{hebrew}`.

Comment: `csquotes` switches the language with `otherlanguage*`, but this only changes the text direction, not the paragraph one, because, as stated in the manual, “it is just a version as environment of `\foreignlanguage`”. For a change in the paragraph direction the correct environment is the unstarred version `otherlanguage` or the command `\selectlanguage`.

Comment: Please see  the updated answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll turn my comment into an answer because I've found a workaround.

The problem here is `csquotes` switches the language with `otherlanguage*`, which it’s just a version as environment of `\foreignlanguage`. In other words, it's meant for phrases, not paragraphs and therefore it only switches the text direction, not the paragraph one. In LTR documents this is hardly noticed, but in RTL ones it’s a real issue. For paragraphs and not just phrases, the proper way to switch the language is the unstarred `otherlanguage` and `\selectlanguage`.

The workaround I found is the following, which redefines the citation format, too (with some additional cleaning up).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[bidi=basic, british]{babel}

\babelprovide[onchar=ids fonts,import]{hebrew}

\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}{FreeSerif} % I'm using a font in TeXLive

\makeatletter
% Fix RTL
\newcommand\wrapotherlang[1]{\csuse{otherlanguage*}{#1}\bbl@dirparastext}
\renewcommand*{\csq@otherlang@star}{\wrapotherlang}%
% Redefine citation
\renewcommand\mkcitation[1]{(#1)}
\def\csq@edquote{%
  \unspace\hfill\csq@tempb
  \csuse{end\csq@blockenvironment}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Blah

\begin{foreigndisplayquote}{hebrew}[Jer 32.1–5]
הַדָּבָר אֲשֶׁר־הָיָה אֶל־יִרְמְיָהוּ מֵאֵת יְהוָה בִּשְׁנַת [בַּ][שָּׁנָה] הָעֲשִׂרִית לְצִדְקִיָּהוּ מֶלֶךְ יְהוּדָה הִיא הַשָּׁנָה שְׁמֹנֶה־עֶשְׂרֵה שָׁנָה לִנְבוּכַדְרֶאצַּר׃ ‎2‏ וְאָז חֵיל מֶלֶךְ בָּבֶל צָרִים עַל־יְרוּשָׁלִָם וְיִרְמְיָהוּ הַנָּבִיא הָיָה כָלוּא בַּחֲצַר הַמַּטָּרָה אֲשֶׁר בֵּית־מֶלֶךְ יְהוּדָה׃ ‎3‏ אֲשֶׁר כְּלָאוֹ צִדְקִיָּהוּ מֶלֶךְ־יְהוּדָה לֵאמֹר מַדּוּעַ אַתָּה נִבָּא לֵאמֹר כֹּה אָמַר יְהוָה הִנְנִי נֹתֵן אֶת־הָעִיר הַזֹּאת בְּיַד מֶלֶךְ־בָּבֶל וּלְכָדָהּ׃ ‎4‏ וְצִדְקִיָּהוּ מֶלֶךְ יְהוּדָה לֹא יִמָּלֵט מִיַּד הַכַּשְׂדִּים כִּי הִנָּתֹן יִנָּתֵן בְּיַד מֶלֶךְ־בָּבֶל וְדִבֶּר־פִּיו עִם־פִּיו וְעֵינָיו אֶת־עֵינָו [עֵינָיו] תִּרְאֶינָה׃ ‎5‏ וּבָבֶל יוֹלִךְ אֶת־צִדְקִיָּהוּ וְשָׁם יִהְיֶה עַד־פָּקְדִי אֹתוֹ נְאֻם־יְהוָה כִּי תִלָּחֲמוּ אֶת־הַכַּשְׂדִּים לֹא תַצְלִיחוּ׃ פ
\end{foreigndisplayquote}
\begin{displayquote}[Jer 32.1–5]
The word that came to Jeremiah from the LORD in the tenth year of     King Zedekiah of Judah, which was the eighteenth year of     Nebuchadrezzar. 2 At that time the army of the king of Babylon was     besieging Jerusalem, and the prophet Jeremiah was confined in the court of the guard that was in the palace of the king of Judah... 
\end{displayquote}
Blah

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Javier! This also fixes up the problem with not mapping back to the main Latin font. Much appreciated. Is this a fix that should go upstream to csquotes in which case is there any way I can help with that process?

Comment: @LyndonDrake Being a hack, I wouldn't be surprised if there were side effects. If you find any problem I can try to find another workaround. I've just realized `csquotes` is in GitHub, so I'll open an issue (but tomorrow).

Comment: The only little wrinkle I can see is that if the (English) citation ends up split across the line ending it looks ugly: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5bq8.png
But I could fix that by attaching the citation only to the English translation, for example.

Comment: Also I've bumped into an example in Latin-only text: https://imgur.com/blpRW9C
which perhaps might be to do with the page break… anyway I'm happy to test anything as I've got a decent-sized file with many examples

Comment: Actually, this kind of alignment is not so simple as inserting an `\hfill`. I'm not very familiar with `csquotes`, so I'm not sure how to deal with it, but very likely `\renewcommand\mkcitation[1]{\mbox{(#1)}}` would help.

Comment: Reported: https://github.com/josephwright/csquotes/issues/55 .

Answer (score 2):

If the only problem is the indentation of the last line of the Hebrew quote, it can be solved with the newly defined environment `foreigndisplayquotex`.

To avoid installing the `TaameyDavidCLM` font I used `Linux Libertine O` which I already had. I removed an invisible space before the first He to left align the first word.

[image: z]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes} % language-aware quoting and display environments
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[bidi=basic, english]{babel}

%
% Languages
%
\babelprovide[import=en-GB,main]{british}
\babelprovide[onchar=ids,fonts,import=he,mapfont=direction]{hebrew}

%\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}[
%Ligatures = TeX,
%Contextuals=Alternate,
%ItalicFont = TaameyDavidCLM-MediumOblique,
%BoldFont = TaameyDavidCLM-Bold,
%BoldItalicFont = TaameyDavidCLM-BoldOblique]%
%{TaameyDavidCLM-Medium}

\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}[Script=Hebrew]{Linux Libertine O} % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<

\makeatletter
\newenvironment*{foreigndisplayquotex}[1] % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
{\csq@getcargs{\csq@bdquote{\csq@lang{#1}}{\csq@endlang}}}
{\hfill\csq@edquote}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{foreigndisplayquotex}{hebrew}[Jer 32.1–5]
    הַדָּבָר אֲשֶׁר־הָיָה אֶל־יִרְמְיָהוּ מֵאֵת יְהוָה בִּשְׁנַת [בַּ][שָּׁנָה] הָעֲשִׂרִית לְצִדְקִיָּהוּ מֶלֶךְ יְהוּדָה הִיא הַשָּׁנָה שְׁמֹנֶה־עֶשְׂרֵה שָׁנָה לִנְבוּכַדְרֶאצַּר׃ ‎2‏ וְאָז חֵיל מֶלֶךְ בָּבֶל צָרִים עַל־יְרוּשָׁלִָם וְיִרְמְיָהוּ הַנָּבִיא הָיָה כָלוּא בַּחֲצַר הַמַּטָּרָה אֲשֶׁר בֵּית־מֶלֶךְ יְהוּדָה׃ ‎3‏ אֲשֶׁר כְּלָאוֹ צִדְקִיָּהוּ מֶלֶךְ־יְהוּדָה לֵאמֹר מַדּוּעַ אַתָּה נִבָּא לֵאמֹר כֹּה אָמַר יְהוָה הִנְנִי נֹתֵן אֶת־הָעִיר הַזֹּאת בְּיַד מֶלֶךְ־בָּבֶל וּלְכָדָהּ׃ ‎4‏ וְצִדְקִיָּהוּ מֶלֶךְ יְהוּדָה לֹא יִמָּלֵט מִיַּד הַכַּשְׂדִּים כִּי הִנָּתֹן יִנָּתֵן בְּיַד מֶלֶךְ־בָּבֶל וְדִבֶּר־פִּיו עִם־פִּיו וְעֵינָיו אֶת־עֵינָו [עֵינָיו] תִּרְאֶינָה׃ ‎5‏ וּבָבֶל יוֹלִךְ אֶת־צִדְקִיָּהוּ וְשָׁם יִהְיֶה עַד־פָּקְדִי אֹתוֹ נְאֻם־יְהוָה כִּי תִלָּחֲמוּ אֶת־הַכַּשְׂדִּים לֹא תַצְלִיחוּ׃ פ
    \end{foreigndisplayquotex}
    \begin{displayquote}[Jer 32.1–5]
        The word that came to Jeremiah from the LORD in the tenth year of King Zedekiah of Judah, which was the eighteenth year of Nebuchadrezzar. 2 At that time the army of the king of Babylon was besieging Jerusalem, and the prophet Jeremiah was confined in the court of the guard that was in the palace of the king of Judah, 3 where King Zedekiah of Judah had confined him. Zedekiah had said, “Why do you prophesy and say: Thus says the LORD: I am going to give this city into the hand of the king of Babylon, and he shall take it; 4 King Zedekiah of Judah shall not escape out of the hands of the Chaldeans, but shall surely be given into the hands of the king of Babylon, and shall speak with him face to face and see him eye to eye; 5 and he shall take Zedekiah to Babylon, and there he shall remain until I attend to him, says the LORD; though you fight against the Chaldeans, you shall not succeed?”
    \end{displayquote}
    
    \selectlanguage{hebrew}
    
    ‏ הַדָּבָר אֲשֶׁר־הָיָה אֶל־יִרְמְיָהוּ מֵאֵת יְהוָה בִּשְׁנַת [בַּ][שָּׁנָה] הָעֲשִׂרִית לְצִדְקִיָּהוּ מֶלֶךְ יְהוּדָה הִיא הַשָּׁנָה שְׁמֹנֶה־עֶשְׂרֵה שָׁנָה לִנְבוּכַדְרֶאצַּר׃ ‎2‏ וְאָז חֵיל מֶלֶךְ בָּבֶל צָרִים עַל־יְרוּשָׁלִָם וְיִרְמְיָהוּ הַנָּבִיא הָיָה כָלוּא בַּחֲצַר הַמַּטָּרָה אֲשֶׁר בֵּית־מֶלֶךְ יְהוּדָה׃ ‎3‏ אֲשֶׁר כְּלָאוֹ צִדְקִיָּהוּ מֶלֶךְ־יְהוּדָה לֵאמֹר מַדּוּעַ אַתָּה נִבָּא לֵאמֹר כֹּה אָמַר יְהוָה הִנְנִי נֹתֵן אֶת־הָעִיר הַזֹּאת בְּיַד מֶלֶךְ־בָּבֶל וּלְכָדָהּ׃ ‎4‏ וְצִדְקִיָּהוּ מֶלֶךְ יְהוּדָה לֹא יִמָּלֵט מִיַּד הַכַּשְׂדִּים כִּי הִנָּתֹן יִנָּתֵן בְּיַד מֶלֶךְ־בָּבֶל וְדִבֶּר־פִּיו עִם־פִּיו וְעֵינָיו אֶת־עֵינָו [עֵינָיו] תִּרְאֶינָה׃ ‎5‏ וּבָבֶל יוֹלִךְ אֶת־צִדְקִיָּהוּ וְשָׁם יִהְיֶה עַד־פָּקְדִי אֹתוֹ נְאֻם־יְהוָה כִּי תִלָּחֲמוּ אֶת־הַכַּשְׂדִּים לֹא תַצְלִיחוּ׃ פ
    
    \selectlanguage{british}
    
    The word that came to Jeremiah from the LORD in the tenth year of King Zedekiah of Judah, which was the eighteenth year of Nebuchadrezzar. 2 At that time the army of the king of Babylon was besieging Jerusalem, and the prophet Jeremiah was confined in the court of the guard that was in the palace of the king of Judah, 3 where King Zedekiah of Judah had confined him. Zedekiah had said, “Why do you prophesy and say: Thus says the LORD: I am going to give this city into the hand of the king of Babylon, and he shall take it; 4 King Zedekiah of Judah shall not escape out of the hands of the Chaldeans, but shall surely be given into the hands of the king of Babylon, and shall speak with him face to face and see him eye to eye; 5 and he shall take Zedekiah to Babylon, and there he shall remain until I attend to him, says the LORD; though you fight against the Chaldeans, you shall not succeed?”
    
    
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE** I found the simplest solution yet, without any fix on `csquotes` : use the second optional argument to insert the `fill`.

The result is the same as other solutions, although it is still not perfect.

Its is worth commenting that the issue is not present using polyglossia as in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/602690/161015 where the right outcome it is finally obtained. (last figure}

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes} % language-aware quoting and display environments
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[bidi=basic, english]{babel}

%
% Languages
%
\babelprovide[import=en-GB,main]{british}
\babelprovide[onchar=ids,fonts,import=he,mapfont=direction]{hebrew} 

\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}[Script=Hebrew]{Linux Libertine O} % changed <<<<<<<<<<<< 

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{foreigndisplayquote}{hebrew}[Jer 32.1–5][\hspace{\fill}] %%using the optional argument to insert a space <<<<<
        הַדָּבָר אֲשֶׁר־הָיָה אֶל־יִרְמְיָהוּ מֵאֵת יְהוָה בִּשְׁנַת [בַּ][שָּׁנָה] הָעֲשִׂרִית לְצִדְקִיָּהוּ מֶלֶךְ יְהוּדָה הִיא הַשָּׁנָה שְׁמֹנֶה־עֶשְׂרֵה שָׁנָה לִנְבוּכַדְרֶאצַּר׃ ‎2‏ וְאָז חֵיל מֶלֶךְ בָּבֶל צָרִים עַל־יְרוּשָׁלִָם וְיִרְמְיָהוּ הַנָּבִיא הָיָה כָלוּא בַּחֲצַר הַמַּטָּרָה אֲשֶׁר בֵּית־מֶלֶךְ יְהוּדָה׃ ‎3‏ אֲשֶׁר כְּלָאוֹ צִדְקִיָּהוּ מֶלֶךְ־יְהוּדָה לֵאמֹר מַדּוּעַ אַתָּה נִבָּא לֵאמֹר כֹּה אָמַר יְהוָה הִנְנִי נֹתֵן אֶת־הָעִיר הַזֹּאת בְּיַד מֶלֶךְ־בָּבֶל וּלְכָדָהּ׃ ‎4‏ וְצִדְקִיָּהוּ מֶלֶךְ יְהוּדָה לֹא יִמָּלֵט מִיַּד הַכַּשְׂדִּים כִּי הִנָּתֹן יִנָּתֵן בְּיַד מֶלֶךְ־בָּבֶל וְדִבֶּר־פִּיו עִם־פִּיו וְעֵינָיו אֶת־עֵינָו [עֵינָיו] תִּרְאֶינָה׃ ‎5‏ וּבָבֶל יוֹלִךְ אֶת־צִדְקִיָּהוּ וְשָׁם יִהְיֶה עַד־פָּקְדִי אֹתוֹ נְאֻם־יְהוָה כִּי תִלָּחֲמוּ אֶת־הַכַּשְׂדִּים לֹא תַצְלִיחוּ׃ פ
    \end{foreigndisplayquote}
    \begin{displayquote}[Jer 32.1–5]
        The word that came to Jeremiah from the LORD in the tenth year of King Zedekiah of Judah, which was the eighteenth year of Nebuchadrezzar. 2 At that time the army of the king of Babylon was besieging Jerusalem, and the prophet Jeremiah was confined in the court of the guard that was in the palace of the king of Judah, 3 where King Zedekiah of Judah had confined him. Zedekiah had said, “Why do you prophesy and say: Thus says the LORD: I am going to give this city into the hand of the king of Babylon, and he shall take it; 4 King Zedekiah of Judah shall not escape out of the hands of the Chaldeans, but shall surely be given into the hands of the king of Babylon, and shall speak with him face to face and see him eye to eye; 5 and he shall take Zedekiah to Babylon, and there he shall remain until I attend to him, says the LORD; though you fight against the Chaldeans, you shall not succeed?”
    \end{displayquote}
    
    \selectlanguage{hebrew}
    
    ‏ הַדָּבָר אֲשֶׁר־הָיָה אֶל־יִרְמְיָהוּ מֵאֵת יְהוָה בִּשְׁנַת [בַּ][שָּׁנָה] הָעֲשִׂרִית לְצִדְקִיָּהוּ מֶלֶךְ יְהוּדָה הִיא הַשָּׁנָה שְׁמֹנֶה־עֶשְׂרֵה שָׁנָה לִנְבוּכַדְרֶאצַּר׃ ‎2‏ וְאָז חֵיל מֶלֶךְ בָּבֶל צָרִים עַל־יְרוּשָׁלִָם וְיִרְמְיָהוּ הַנָּבִיא הָיָה כָלוּא בַּחֲצַר הַמַּטָּרָה אֲשֶׁר בֵּית־מֶלֶךְ יְהוּדָה׃ ‎3‏ אֲשֶׁר כְּלָאוֹ צִדְקִיָּהוּ מֶלֶךְ־יְהוּדָה לֵאמֹר מַדּוּעַ אַתָּה נִבָּא לֵאמֹר כֹּה אָמַר יְהוָה הִנְנִי נֹתֵן אֶת־הָעִיר הַזֹּאת בְּיַד מֶלֶךְ־בָּבֶל וּלְכָדָהּ׃ ‎4‏ וְצִדְקִיָּהוּ מֶלֶךְ יְהוּדָה לֹא יִמָּלֵט מִיַּד הַכַּשְׂדִּים כִּי הִנָּתֹן יִנָּתֵן בְּיַד מֶלֶךְ־בָּבֶל וְדִבֶּר־פִּיו עִם־פִּיו וְעֵינָיו אֶת־עֵינָו [עֵינָיו] תִּרְאֶינָה׃ ‎5‏ וּבָבֶל יוֹלִךְ אֶת־צִדְקִיָּהוּ וְשָׁם יִהְיֶה עַד־פָּקְדִי אֹתוֹ נְאֻם־יְהוָה כִּי תִלָּחֲמוּ אֶת־הַכַּשְׂדִּים לֹא תַצְלִיחוּ׃ פ
    
    \selectlanguage{british}
    
    The word that came to Jeremiah from the LORD in the tenth year of King Zedekiah of Judah, which was the eighteenth year of Nebuchadrezzar. 2 At that time the army of the king of Babylon was besieging Jerusalem, and the prophet Jeremiah was confined in the court of the guard that was in the palace of the king of Judah, 3 where King Zedekiah of Judah had confined him. Zedekiah had said, “Why do you prophesy and say: Thus says the LORD: I am going to give this city into the hand of the king of Babylon, and he shall take it; 4 King Zedekiah of Judah shall not escape out of the hands of the Chaldeans, but shall surely be given into the hands of the king of Babylon, and shall speak with him face to face and see him eye to eye; 5 and he shall take Zedekiah to Babylon, and there he shall remain until I attend to him, says the LORD; though you fight against the Chaldeans, you shall not succeed?”
    
    
\end{document}
```

**Using polyglossia**

[image: zp]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes} % language-aware quoting and display environments
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}

\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Linux Libertine O}
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Ligatures=NoCommon]{Linux Libertine O}   

\begin{document}        

\begin{foreigndisplayquote}{hebrew}[Jer 32.1–5][\enspace]
    הַדָּבָר אֲשֶׁר־הָיָה אֶל־יִרְמְיָהוּ מֵאֵת יְהוָה בִּשְׁנַת [בַּ][שָּׁנָה] הָעֲשִׂרִית לְצִדְקִיָּהוּ מֶלֶךְ יְהוּדָה הִיא הַשָּׁנָה שְׁמֹנֶה־עֶשְׂרֵה שָׁנָה לִנְבוּכַדְרֶאצַּר׃ 2 וְאָז חֵיל מֶלֶךְ בָּבֶל צָרִים עַל־יְרוּשָׁלִָם וְיִרְמְיָהוּ הַנָּבִיא הָיָה כָלוּא בַּחֲצַר הַמַּטָּרָה אֲשֶׁר בֵּית־מֶלֶךְ יְהוּדָה׃ 3 אֲשֶׁר כְּלָאוֹ צִדְקִיָּהוּ מֶלֶךְ־יְהוּדָה לֵאמֹר מַדּוּעַ אַתָּה נִבָּא לֵאמֹר כֹּה אָמַר יְהוָה הִנְנִי נֹתֵן אֶת־הָעִיר הַזֹּאת בְּיַד מֶלֶךְ־בָּבֶל וּלְכָדָהּ׃ 4 וְצִדְקִיָּהוּ מֶלֶךְ יְהוּדָה לֹא יִמָּלֵט מִיַּד הַכַּשְׂדִּים כִּי הִנָּתֹן יִנָּתֵן בְּיַד מֶלֶךְ־בָּבֶל וְדִבֶּר־פִּיו עִם־פִּיו וְעֵינָיו אֶת־עֵינָו [עֵינָיו] תִּרְאֶינָה׃ 5 וּבָבֶל יוֹלִךְ אֶת־צִדְקִיָּהוּ וְשָׁם יִהְיֶה עַד־פָּקְדִי אֹתוֹ נְאֻם־יְהוָה כִּי תִלָּחֲמוּ אֶת־הַכַּשְׂדִּים לֹא תַצְלִיחוּ׃ פ
\end{foreigndisplayquote}   

    \begin{displayquote}[Jer 32.1–5]
        The word that came to Jeremiah from the LORD in the tenth year of King Zedekiah of Judah, which was the eighteenth year of Nebuchadrezzar. 2 At that time the army of the king of Babylon was besieging Jerusalem, and the prophet Jeremiah was confined in the court of the guard that was in the palace of the king of Judah, 3 where King Zedekiah of Judah had confined him. Zedekiah had said, “Why do you prophesy and say: Thus says the LORD: I am going to give this city into the hand of the king of Babylon, and he shall take it; 4 King Zedekiah of Judah shall not escape out of the hands of the Chaldeans, but shall surely be given into the hands of the king of Babylon, and shall speak with him face to face and see him eye to eye; 5 and he shall take Zedekiah to Babylon, and there he shall remain until I attend to him, says the LORD; though you fight against the Chaldeans, you shall not succeed?”
    \end{displayquote}
    
    \selectlanguage{hebrew}
    
    ‏ הַדָּבָר אֲשֶׁר־הָיָה אֶל־יִרְמְיָהוּ מֵאֵת יְהוָה בִּשְׁנַת [בַּ][שָּׁנָה] הָעֲשִׂרִית לְצִדְקִיָּהוּ מֶלֶךְ יְהוּדָה הִיא הַשָּׁנָה שְׁמֹנֶה־עֶשְׂרֵה שָׁנָה לִנְבוּכַדְרֶאצַּר׃ ‎2‏ וְאָז חֵיל מֶלֶךְ בָּבֶל צָרִים עַל־יְרוּשָׁלִָם וְיִרְמְיָהוּ הַנָּבִיא הָיָה כָלוּא בַּחֲצַר הַמַּטָּרָה אֲשֶׁר בֵּית־מֶלֶךְ יְהוּדָה׃ ‎3‏ אֲשֶׁר כְּלָאוֹ צִדְקִיָּהוּ מֶלֶךְ־יְהוּדָה לֵאמֹר מַדּוּעַ אַתָּה נִבָּא לֵאמֹר כֹּה אָמַר יְהוָה הִנְנִי נֹתֵן אֶת־הָעִיר הַזֹּאת בְּיַד מֶלֶךְ־בָּבֶל וּלְכָדָהּ׃ ‎4‏ וְצִדְקִיָּהוּ מֶלֶךְ יְהוּדָה לֹא יִמָּלֵט מִיַּד הַכַּשְׂדִּים כִּי הִנָּתֹן יִנָּתֵן בְּיַד מֶלֶךְ־בָּבֶל וְדִבֶּר־פִּיו עִם־פִּיו וְעֵינָיו אֶת־עֵינָו [עֵינָיו] תִּרְאֶינָה׃ ‎5‏ וּבָבֶל יוֹלִךְ אֶת־צִדְקִיָּהוּ וְשָׁם יִהְיֶה עַד־פָּקְדִי אֹתוֹ נְאֻם־יְהוָה כִּי תִלָּחֲמוּ אֶת־הַכַּשְׂדִּים לֹא תַצְלִיחוּ׃ פ
    
    \selectlanguage{british}
    
    The word that came to Jeremiah from the LORD in the tenth year of King Zedekiah of Judah, which was the eighteenth year of Nebuchadrezzar. 2 At that time the army of the king of Babylon was besieging Jerusalem, and the prophet Jeremiah was confined in the court of the guard that was in the palace of the king of Judah, 3 where King Zedekiah of Judah had confined him. Zedekiah had said, “Why do you prophesy and say: Thus says the LORD: I am going to give this city into the hand of the king of Babylon, and he shall take it; 4 King Zedekiah of Judah shall not escape out of the hands of the Chaldeans, but shall surely be given into the hands of the king of Babylon, and shall speak with him face to face and see him eye to eye; 5 and he shall take Zedekiah to Babylon, and there he shall remain until I attend to him, says the LORD; though you fight against the Chaldeans, you shall not succeed?”
    
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Do you think there's a way to fix the csquotes package to include this then? Apparently it now works with polyglossia (I noticed your additional response on the other post) so it seems like a babel-specific problem now rather than intended behaviour?

Comment: @Lyndon Drake You are right. I tested your file using polyglossia and there is no problem with the last line. Replace the four lines of babel with  `\usepackage{polyglossia}
 \setdefaultlanguage{british}
 \setotherlanguage{hebrew}
 
 \newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{Linux Libertine O}
 \newfontfamily\englishfont[Ligatures=NoCommon]{Linux Libertine O}`

Comment: Thanks @Simon Dispa - unfortunately there are a variety of other reasons why I need to use Babel

Comment: @Lyndon Drake Of course!.  I put the polyglossia solution to help to pinpoint the origin. IMHO it is not `csquotes`. The "fixes" might help, but do not produce a perfect result.

Comment: @SimonDispa This confirm the problem is `csquotes` because `polyglossia` _does_ change the paragraph direction with `otherlanguage*`. It's a different package, after all, so don't expect the same behavior. So very likely `csquotes` has to discriminate which package is being used.

Comment: @Javier Bezos Thank you for your feedback!